# Cannot install NumPy using pip and import it

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm actually using Matplotlib and Numpy for a Python script on a ssh.

I had to creat a virtual python3 environment on my ssh account.

then, I made: `pip3 install numpy`

and everything worked well:

```
Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/61/11b05cc37ccdaabad89f04dbdc2a02905cf6de6f9b05816dba843beed328/numpy-1.14.3-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.14.3
```

pip3 show numpy

```
Name: numpy
Version: 1.14.3
Summary: NumPy: array processing for numbers, strings, records, and objects.
Home-page: http://www.numpy.org
Author: Travis E. Oliphant et al.
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: /panhome/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

Then, in my script I put the PYTHONPATH such:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/panhome/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

but I actually get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/pandata/me/LEPIWASP/blast_database/public_scripts-master/Diamond_BLAST_add_taxonomic_info/Diamond_blast_to_taxid.py", line 25, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "/panhome/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
    from . import cbook
  File "/panhome/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/panhome/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/panhome/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/panhome/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/panhome/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/panhome/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: cannot import name multiarray
```

I already tried to unistall numpy and reinstate it several times.

Thanks for your help.

```
Import command line in the script file: 
# imports
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import os
import sys
from optparse import OptionParser  # TODO: update to argparser
import datetime
import logging
import logging.handlers
import matplotlib
# this code added to prevent this error:
# self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName,
# className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
# _tkinter.TclError: no display name and
# no $DISPLAY environment variable
# Force matplotlib to not use any Xwindows backend.
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
```

Here is my script to run the process:

```
#PBS -S /bin/bash
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=8
#PBS -e /pandata/me/LEPIWASP/blast_database/tax_name_candidates_sp1.error
#PBS -o /pandata/me/LEPIWASP/blast_database/tax_name_candidates_sp1.out
#PBS -q q1hour
#PBS -N tax_name_candidates_sp1


export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/panhome/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/
diamond_tab_output=/pandata/me/LEPIWASP/blast_database/matches.m8
Diamond_blast_to_taxid=/pandata/me/LEPIWASP/blast_database/public_scripts-master/Diamond_BLAST_add_taxonomic_info/Diamond_blast_to_taxid.py

taxid=/pandata/me/LEPIWASP/blast_database/gi_taxid_prot.dmp

categories=/pandata/me/LEPIWASP/blast_database/categories.dmp

names=/pandata/me/LEPIWASP/blast_database/names.dmp

description=/pandata/me/LEPIWASP/blast_database/acc_to_des.tab

$Diamond_blast_to_taxid -i $diamond_tab_output -t $taxid -c $categories -n $names -d $description -o outfile_sp1.tab
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you import Numpy?

Comment: It is not my script but I added in my frst comment the import commande lines.

Comment: Can you post the script you're using? I suspect you want to activate the virtual env rather than manipulate the PATH manually.

Comment: For sure (I added it on the first comment)

Comment: What happens if you don't set `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: I get: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "/pandata/me/LEPIWASP/blast_database/public_scripts-master/Diamond_BLAST_add_taxonomic_info/Diamond_blast_to_taxid .py", line 25, in <module> import matplotlib ImportError: No module named matplotlib`

Comment: as @pneumatics says I'd say that before executing the script you need to activate the environment. You may do it with `conda activate env-name` or using `source path-to-env/bin/activate` 

Did you activate the environment after creation? @Grendel26.

Could you show how you execute the script?